# Benefits Of PGN Files

Tags: beginner

I’m wanting to improve at Chess and reduce my number of mistakes and blunders in order for me to win more games.
Can Pgn files help me with my quest to improve?
If not then what can I do?
What is a good strategy to use in order improve my rating.

Answer (score 2):

I am only going to address this question here: `Can Pgn files help me with my quest to improve?`

Getting your games into `pgn` or any other other format does not increase your strength of play and, as a consequence, your rating. It's only a format of how you keep the record of your games.
However it will definitely have an influence on your overall experience of analysing, sharing or archiving your games.

Answer (score 0):

Like what pavel Nefyodov has stated above, "Getting your games into pgn or any other other format does not increase your strength of play".

However, you should try to play a lot of (serious) chess and review your games. Try to start slow games e.g. 10mins game. You should also study multiple openings and critical endgames positions that will help you in your chess games. Also, try to be open to criticism about your games, so you can receive feedback and learn how to improve your gameplay strategy. You should also try to review games played by high rated players, to get a sense of how pros play, and take notice of how they activate their pieces, or use a specific opening. More tips can be found [here](https://www.chesskid.com/learn/articles/top-10-tips-to-becoming-a-better-chess-player)